# Clone form and increment

Tags: jquery, forms, clone

I have a form below that I want to clone, increment the id(att1) and it's inputs, textareas etc and append to the attendees div. Any help much appreciated. Been wrecking my head...

All I have is...

```
$(function () {
        var index = 1;


    $(".add").click(function () {
            index++;

        $("#att1").clone(true).removeAttr("id").attr("id", "att" + index).appendTo("#attendees");
            alert(index);
    });
});
```

Html:

```
    <div id="attendees">
            <div id="att1">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend><span class="legend">Attendee 1 Booking Details</span></legend>
                        <p name="test">
                        <label for="A_Title_1">Title: <span class="req">*</span></label>
                        <input name="A_Title_1" id="A_Title_1" value="" type="text" class="f_input" />
                        </p>

                        <p>
                        <label for="A_Forename_1">Forename: <span class="req">*</span></label>
                        <input name="A_Forename_1" id="A_Forename_1" type="text" class="f_input" />
                        </p>

                        <p>
                        <label for="A_Surname_1">Surname: <span class="req">*</span></label>
                        <input name="A_Surname_1" id="A_Surname_1" type="text" class="f_input" />
                        </p>

                        <p>
                        <label for="A_Info_1">Additional Info: </label>
                        <textarea name="A_Info_1" id="A_Info_1" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
                        <span class="info">Please include any infomation relating to dietary/ access/special requirements you might have.</span>
                        </p>
                    </fieldset>
                    </div>
<a href="#" class="add">Add more</a>

    </div>
```

Comment: I see you don't post any JavaScript. Do you need help with every single line of code required or do you have problems with some specific step?

Comment: I have edited the text above with what I have which is very little. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VuT4g/1/).

Add a class `attendee` to the `div id="att1"`

```
 <div id="att1" class="attendee">
```

**And the JS:**

```
$(function(){
    var template = $('#attendees .attendee:first').clone(),
        attendeesCount = 1;

    var addAttendee = function(){
        attendeesCount++;
        var attendee = template.clone().find(':input').each(function(){
            var newId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.length-1) + attendeesCount;
            $(this).prev().attr('for', newId); // update label for (assume prev sib is label)
            this.name = this.id = newId; // update id and name (assume the same)
        }).end() // back to .attendee
        .attr('id', 'att' + attendeesCount) // update attendee id
        .prependTo('#attendees'); // add to container
    };

    $('.add').click(addAttendee); // attach event
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    empty_html = $('#att1').html();

    $('.add').click(function() {

        last_id = $('#attendees div:last').attr('id').replace('attr','');

        next_id = last_id++;

        new_div = $('<div id="' + next_id + '">' + empty_html +'<div>');

        $('#attendees').append(new_div);

    });
```

Requires a few tweaks to your HTML, I would move the add link out of the attendees div.

Answer (score 0):

This example might help you. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/4707/)

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $(document).on('click','#addScnt', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click','#remScnt', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

i know it's old thread.. i just wanna share simply way to increment id. i'm using same class in all cloned element

UPDATE :

this more elegance way :

```
var clone_counter = 1; // global variable
$('.clone').click(function(){
   $('.clonethis').clone();
   console.log(clone_counter);
   clone_counter++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[I posted this same answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22981330/839847), but here I think it applies to this question too.

I created an 'original' element and hid it on the page. I appended "---" to the value of any attribute that needed to be incremented within any child elements of the original.

Whenever the user clicked a button to create a clone of the original, I created a clone, then globally replaced "---" with the current index within that clone's HTML. Something like this:

```
var $clone = $original.clone();
var cloneHTML = $clone.html().replace(/---/g, incrementedFieldNum);
$clone.html(cloneHTML);

// Insert and show the clone after the original
$original.after($clone);
```

I used a data attribute to store updated values of incrementedFieldNum (not shown in the code above).

Hopefully that helps. It's a lot less code and it's a more general solution I think. I had a lot of nested elements that needed to have incremented IDs and names, so a solution like the one from @Fierceblood was impractical.