# jQuery Datepicker set start and end date of dynamically added datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have dynamically added datepicker textboxes of id's `TrainingPeriodStart[]` and `TrainingPeriodEnd[]`. I need to target each pair to set their proper start and end date.

The setting of the start and end date is found on the documentation [link here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range).

I have the code below in mind but it does not work:

```
    var inputName = '';
    var number = '';

    $('input[id^="TrainingPeriodStart"]').click(function() {
        inputName = $(this).attr('id');
        number = inputName.substr(inputName.length - 3); // get [number]
    }).datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function( selected ) {
            $('#TrainingPeriodEnd'+number).datepicker( "option", "minDate", 
                selected )
        }
    });

    $('input[id^="TrainingPeriodEnd"]').click(function() {
        inputName = $(this).attr('id');
        number = inputName.substr(inputName.length - 3); // get [number]
    }).datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function( selected ) {
            $('#TrainingPeriodStart'+number).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", 
                selected )
        }
    });
```

Basically I want to target datepicker pairs with their `[number]` attribute and setting their minimum and maximum dates to restrict the user from selecting illegal date ranges.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/SCXMD/2/ . What do you mean "does not work?".

Comment: @mccannf: Thank you very much for the confirmation. I actually use a cloning script for these datepicker pairs like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4400887/1685185. The datepicker works but not the actual start/end events :( Does cloning these affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clone elements, you need to add new click events to the cloned elements in order for the event to be triggered:

```
$(function() {
    var inputName = '';
    var number = '';

    var template = $('#training .trainingperiod:first').clone(),
        trainingPeriodCount = 1;

    var addTrainingPeriod = function(){
        trainingPeriodCount++;
        var trainingPeriod = template.clone().find(':input').each(function(){
            var newId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.length-1) + trainingPeriodCount;
            this.name = this.id = newId; // update id and name (assume the same)
        }).end() // back to .trainingperiod
        .attr('id', 'TrainingPeriod' + trainingPeriodCount) // update attendee id
        .prependTo('#training'); // add to container

        $('#TrainingPeriod' + trainingPeriodCount).find('input[id^="TrainingPeriodStart"]').datepicker({
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function( selected ) {
                var thisInput = $(this).attr('id');
                var thisNumber = thisInput.substr(thisInput.length - 3);
                $('#TrainingPeriodEnd'+thisNumber).datepicker( "option", "minDate", 
                    selected )
            }
        });
        $('#TrainingPeriod' + trainingPeriodCount).find('input[id^="TrainingPeriodEnd"]').datepicker({
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function( selected ) {
                var thisInput = $(this).attr('id');
                var thisNumber = thisInput.substr(thisInput.length - 3);
                $('#TrainingPeriodStart'+thisNumber).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", 
                    selected )
            }
        });        
    };

    $('.add').click(addTrainingPeriod); // attach event

    $('input[id^="TrainingPeriodStart"]').click(function() {
        inputName = $(this).attr('id');
        number = inputName.substr(inputName.length - 3); // get [number]
    }).datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function( selected ) {
            $('#TrainingPeriodEnd'+number).datepicker( "option", "minDate", 
                selected )
        }
    });

    $('input[id^="TrainingPeriodEnd"]').click(function() {
        inputName = $(this).attr('id');
        number = inputName.substr(inputName.length - 3); // get [number]
    }).datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function( selected ) {
            $('#TrainingPeriodStart'+number).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", 
                selected )
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/SCXMD/5/).