# Dynamically generating form elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

There are multiple paragraphs in the page. Each paragraph must be followed by a div with two buttons `Add` and `Edit`. Clicking the `Add` button should create a textarea dynamically above it.

Related references that didn't work:

- [How to use jQuery to add form elements dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744594/how-to-use-jquery-to-add-form-elements-dynamically)
- [How to add (clone) form fields using jQuery and increment ids and names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578111/how-to-add-clone-form-fields-using-jquery-and-increment-ids-and-names)

**DEMO**

---

[image]

---

HTML code:

```
<div id="notes"></div>
```

In my JavaScipt:

```
<script>
// get notes in json format from php array
var notes = <?php echo json_encode($notes); ?>;

// call the scan function to iterate through the notes
scan(notes);

function scan(obj)
{
    jQuery.each(obj, function(key, val) {
    if (val instanceof Object) {
    for ( var v in val ) {
        if (val[v]['type'] == 'Topic') {
           $("#notes").append('<h2 class="topic">'+val[v]['content']+'</h2>');
        }
        if (val[v]['type'] == 'Subtopic') {
           $("#notes").append('<h4 class="subtopic">'+val[v]['content']+'</h4>');
        }
        if (val[v]['type'] == 'Concept') {
           $("#notes").append('<h5 class="concept">'+val[v]['content']+'</h5>');
        }
        if (val[v]['type'] == 'Paragraph') {
           $("#notes").append('<p>'+val[v]['content']+'</p>');

           // append input for all paragraphs
           $('#notes').append('<div class="paragraphs">');
           $('#notes').append('<div id="block">');
           $('#notes').append('<p class="edit"></p>');
           $('#notes').append('<p>');
           $('#notes').append('<div id="para">');
           $('#notes').append('<p><textarea cols="40" rows="2" id="textarea"></textarea></p>');
           $('#notes').append('<button id="add" class="add success tiny">Add</button>');
           $('#notes').append('&nbsp;');
           $('#notes').append('<button id="startEdit" class="canEdit tiny">Edit</button>');
           $('#notes').append('</div>');
           $('#notes').append('</p>');
           $('#notes').append('</div>');
           $('#notes').append('</div>');

        }
        scan(val[v]);
        }   
     }
  });
};

// Add paragraph button

i = 1;
$('#textarea'+i).hide();

text = $('#textarea'+i).text();
var data = '{"subject_id":'+$subject_id+',"teacher_id":'+$teacher_id+',"editedContent":"'+text+'"}';

$('.paragraphs').on('click', '#add'+i, function() {
  if ( $('#add'+i).text() == "Add" ) {

    ajaxRequest(data, 'editNotes', 'POST');  // POST request on editNotes

    $('#textarea'+i).show();
    $('#add'+i).text('Save');
    $('#textarea'+i).focus(function() {
        this.select();
    });
  }
  else if ( $('#add'+i).text() == "Save" ) {

    ajaxRequest(data, 'saveNotes', 'POST');  // POST request on saveNotes

    if ($('#textarea'+i).val() == ''){
      alert('Enter something...');
    } else {
      $('#add'+i).text("Add");
      $('#textarea'+i).hide();
      var overview = $('#textarea'+i).val();
      i++;
      console.log('after: i='+i);
      $('.paragraphs').append('<div id="block'+i+'"><p class="edit'+i+'">'+overview+'</p><div id="para'+i+'"><p><textarea cols="40" rows="2" id="textarea'+i+'"></textarea></p><button id="add'+i+'" class="add'+i+' success tiny">Add</button><button id="startEdit'+i+'" class="canEdit'+i+' tiny">Edit</button></div></div>');
    }
  }

});
</script>
```

How do I add the form elements dynamically with incremental id and class names?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Usually a Question involves the use of a `?` (*question-mark*). What was your question?

Comment: That's not how DOM works. You can't insert the opening and the closing tags separately.

Comment: I suggest to avoid doing this..whats wrong with doing it in html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately append does not work like it may seem, when you submit something like:

```
$('#element').append('<div>start here'):
$('#element').append('end here</div>'):
```

The very first call sent will close the div, it will actually create 2 separate elements. One way to help with this rather than having a large append as it can get kinda messy, is to create a variable and place all the elements into that variable and append it.

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/h8V93/

```
var appends='<div class="paragraphs">'
            +'<div id="block">'
            +'<p class="edit"></p>'
            +'<p>'
            +'<div id="para">'
            +'<p><textarea cols="40" rows="2" id="textarea"></textarea></p>'
            +'<button id="add" class="add success tiny">Add</button>'
            +'&nbsp;'
            +'<button id="startEdit" class="canEdit tiny">Edit</button>'
            +'</div>'
            +'</p>'
            +'</div>'
            +'</div>';

            $('#notes').append(appends);
```

I hope this helps.

**Update**

Edit for further reading, the best way to actually do this is to create an html page as a separate file and include it like so:::

```
$.get("<urlhere>", function (data) {
    //Append, After, Before, Prepend data or whatever you want to do with it.
});
```

This is very convenient in GM or TM scripts where you keep the html file on your own server.

Hope this update helps future readers.

in recent versions of TM (tampermonkey), because of added cross domain origin policies, use GM_xmlhttpRequest -> http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest

Comment: Anytime, glad to be of help.

Comment: Please, refer to my updated question. I have added two questions.

Comment: Ah no worries. Those questions are pretty unrelated to the original post and I believe both of those questions deserve their own separate threads so they can gain more exposure to be answered. Start up a new one, I am sure someone will assist.

Comment: How do I increment the ids and class names? I added a counter before the scan function `var counter=0;` and then incremented the counter by 1 before the appends. But when I use it in the classes and ids `+'<p class="edit'+counter+'"></p>'` it returns `editNaN`. Why is that?