# How to iterate over each select element in a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, each

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578111/how-to-add-clone-form-fields-using-jquery-and-increment-ids-and-names) post for cloning form fields with incrementing ids - works great.

But, in my adaptation, I have added a select box in the cloned form. The select box's id increments as it should. The goal is that when a particular choice (always the same in every cloned field) is selected, some hidden inputs are revealed.

I can do this with javascript for a set # of known select elements, but I can't figure out how to iterate of each cloned `select`, since the user can create as many as they need?

A simple version is thus:

HTML

```
<div id="zero_form" style="display:none;">
    <p>
        <input id='box1_' type="text" style="width:125px" placeholder='Type'>
        <br>
        <select id='box2_' class="first_input" style="width: 200px;" placeholder="Choose a Value">
            <option value="Choose a Value">Choose a Value</option>
            <option>NEGATIVE</option>
            <option>EQUIVOCAL</option>
            <option>POSITIVE</option>
        </select>
        <input id='box3_' style='display:none;' placeholder='Score #1'>
        <input id='box4_' style='display:none;' placeholder='Score #2'>
        <input id='box5_' style='display:none;' placeholder='%'>
        <input id='box6_' type="text"  placeholder="Enter Comments" style="width:200px">
        <input type="button" id="remove" class="removebutton" value="Delete">
        <br>
    </p>
</div>
<!-- end hidden clone div-->
<form>
    <p> 
        <span id="add" class="addbutton">Add another row</span>
    </p>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    // show hidden inputs on POSITIVE selection
    $('input [type=select]').each(function(){
        var sel = $(this).val();
        if (sel == 'POSITIVE'){
            $(this).parent().find('[type=text]').show();}
        else {
            $(this).parent().find('[type=text]').hide();}
              });

   // clone fields  
    var form_index = 0;
    $("#add").click(function () {
        form_index++;
        $(this).parent().before($("#zero_form").clone().attr("id", "zero_form" + form_index));
        $("#zero_form" + form_index).css("display", "inline");
        $("#zero_form" + form_index + " :input").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + form_index);
        });
        $("#remove"+form_index).click(function () {
            $(this).closest("div").remove();
        });
    });

});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W48g3/1/)

There is something I'm not understanding about the syntax within my `each` function? Help please!

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cpm8r/1/ ?

Comment: your jsfiddle working fine. What do you want?

Comment: @Arun P Johny has it pretty close to what I want. The only problem is that the hidden input fields only pertain to the select choice. I want them visible when the select choice is 'POSITIVE', but removed if not. The other elements should always be there. In your example, any selection other than 'POSITIVE' removes the other fields.

Comment: @user1837608 so which are text fields related to select

Comment: @Arun P Johny - I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cpm8r/2/) with what I was trying to do. Thanks for the quick help! Now I need to see why my attempt to iterate didn't work. Any tips?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cpm8r/3/

Comment: Thanks - I did the same thing in my reply as well!

Comment: @user1837608 did it solve the problem... if so I will post it as an answer

Comment: Yes, it did solve the problem and I'd be happy to vote your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you need to use change handlers to listen to the change event of the select element
- since you have dynamic elements, you need to use event delegation
- to make element access easier, I have made some dom changes also - added some class attributes

  Choose a Value
              NEGATIVE
              EQUIVOCAL
              POSITIVE

  Add another row

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // show hidden inputs on POSITIVE selection
    $(document).on('change', '.zero_form select.first_input', function () {
        var sel = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().find('input.positive').toggle(sel == 'POSITIVE');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.zero_form .removebutton', function () {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
    });

    // clone fields  
    var form_index = 0;
    $("#add").click(function () {
        form_index++;
        var $from = $("#zero_form").clone().attr("id", "zero_form" + form_index).insertBefore($(this).parent())
        $from.css("display", "inline");
        $from.find(":input").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + form_index);
        });
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cpm8r/)