# Generate variables that equal dynamically created form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, variables, for-loop

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004355/how-to-iterate-over-each-select-element-in-a-dynamic-form), I learned how to generate dynamic form elements with increasing element Ids.

Now, I'm having trouble figuring out a way to assign variables that equal the dynamically created form elements.

My form has six inputs with IDs as such:

```
box1_
box2_
box3_
box4_
box5_
box6_
```

Each clone of the form, adds an incrementing numeral to the end of the id, such that the first clone has boxes ending in `1`, the second clone has boxes ending in `2`, and such.

Here is my form cloning code, borrowed from the answer to my earlier question:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // show hidden inputs on POSITIVE selection
    $(document).on('change', '.zero_form select.first_input', function () {
        var sel = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().find('.hide').toggle(sel == 'POSITIVE');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.zero_form .removebutton', function () {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
    });

    // clone fields  
    var form_index = 0;
    $("#add").click(function () {
        form_index++;
        $(this).parent().before($("#zero_form").clone().attr("id", "zero_form" + form_index));
        $("#zero_form" + form_index).css("display", "inline");
        $("#zero_form" + form_index + " :input").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + form_index);
        });
    });

});
```

I would like to dynamically create variables that capture the value of each element as it is created. For example, if I created two cloned fields, I would have inputs with the IDs:

```
box1_1, box2_1, box3_1, box4_1, box5_1, box6_1 &
box1_2, box2_2, box3_2, box4_2, box5_2, box6_2
```

I would want the variables as such:

```
var part1_1 = $('#box1_1').val();
var part2_1 = $('#box2_1').val();
...
var part1_6 = $('#box1_6').val();
var part2_6 = $('#box2_6').val(); etc..
```

This is what I've tried as an attempt to generate dynamic variables - I don't get any console errors, but I cannot verify that the variables exist and are accessible within my function?

script

```
function printOut() {
    var dxOut = 'Output\n';

    var part1_ = [];
    var part2_ = [];
    var part3_ = [];
    var part4_ = [];
    var part5_ = [];
    var part6_ = [];



// I'm not sure how to set the length of i to the # of inputs, so I chose 30 for now
    for (var i=1; i <= 30; i++){
    part1_[i] = $('#box1_'+i).val();
    part2_[i] = $('#box2_'+i).val();
    part3_[i] = $('#box3_'+i).val();
    part4_[i] = $('#box4_'+i).val();
    part5_[i] = $('#box5_'+i).val();
    part6_[i] = $('#box6_'+i).val();
    }

    return part1_;
    return part2_;
    return part3_;
    return part4_;
    return part5_;
    return part6_;

    dxOut += part1_1 +'\n'+part2_1+'\n'+part3_1;

        $('#output').val(dxOut);

  }
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cpm8r/6/), in case it helps.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 ways to do this:

## Create an array

The easiest way, and probably the preferred method if you have no particular reason to need explicit variables for each would be to use an array.

```
// Adding to array
var values = [];
$('#zero_form ' + form_index + ' input').each(function() {
   values.push($(this).val()));
});

// Outputting from array
values.forEach(function(value) {
   // do something with value
});

// Access just one
console.log(values[0]);
```

## Create an object

This is very similar to the array method, though it allows you to name each item, if that is important later.

```
// Adding to object
var values = {};
$('#zero_form ' + form_index + ' input').each(function() {
   values[$(this).attr('name')] = ($(this).val()));
});

// Outputting from object
for (var name in values) {
   if (values.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
       var value = values[name];
       // do something with value
   }
});

// Access just one
console.log(values['item1']);
// or
console.log(values.item1);
```

## Create dynamic variables

If you really need them to be individual variables, you can create and access them by treating `window` like an object.

In your particular case, I would NOT do things with this technique. I only include it to show how to create dynamically named variables.

```
// Adding to window/global
$('#zero_form ' + form_index + ' input').each(function() {
   window['input_' + $(this).attr('name')] = ($(this).val()));
});

// Outputting from window/global
for (var name in window) {
   if (/^input_/.test(name) && window.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
       var value = window[name];
       // do something with value
   }
});

// Access just one
console.log(window['item1']);
// or
console.log(item1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanations. This type of manipulation is a little more complex than I've been doing. I think your 2nd option may work - but can I use `values.hasOwnProperty(id)` instead of name? Also, is it possible to make unique variables equal to the input values? I'm not sure if that is already what your example intends to do.

Comment: Yes, you can use any identifier, like the ID. Also that is what the example does. `values[$(this).attr('name')] = ($(this).val())); });` sets the value of the input to a field that uses its name. To use the ID, just change `attr('name')` to `attr('id')`.

Comment: One more clarification, how do the variables generated get recalled individually? Meaning, if I only wanted, say, the variable whose value refers to the input with id=box2_2?

Comment: I updated my answer to include an example of accessing just one of each. Assumes that 'item1' was the name of the element.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create an empty array

2) Loop through you element

3) fill the array as you go

```
emptyArray = [];

$("#zero_form" + form_index + " :input").each(function () {
  var inputValue = $(this).value;  
  emptyArray.push(inputValue);
});
```