# copy select element in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic table where I add rows dynamically when the user clicks a button.

My button call the following function :

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRowTuy($('#AmonttableTuy tbody'), 'AmontTuy');" />
```

My function adds a new rows to my table. It include text fields, inputs and select.

I have no problem for the creation of new inputs and text, but for the select, I want copy an existing select and change its id. That's my problem.

This is the function where I create a new rows in my table:

```
function addRowTuy(table, value)
{
var nbrow = table.children().size();
    table.append( "<tr>"+
    "<td>"+(nbrow+1)+"</td>"+
    "<td><input id='"+value+(nbrow+1)+"Diam"+"'/></td>"+
    "<td><input id='"+value+(nbrow+1)+"Long"+"'/></td>"+
    "<td>"+$("#AmontTuy1Type")+"</td>"+ //This is where I want copy the select element
    "<td><input id='"+value+(nbrow+1)+"Rugo"+"'/></td>"+
"</tr>");
}
```

Have you an idea on the way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [.clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: I have looked at .clone and tried, but I didn't success when I use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
"<td>"+$("#AmontTuy1Type").clone().attr('id', 'newID').html() +
```

You need to clone and add its html to your string, not the element itself. Or create a td element and append the clone to it.

**Update:**

Yeah, you're right, html() only takes the options, not the select itself. Try this:

```
"<td>"+"<select id='newID'>" + $("#AmontTuy1Type").html() + "</select>" +
```

Comment: this copy only the option of the select and not all the select. It is strange because "AmontTuy1Type" is the id of the select

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this. Below links will be helpful for you.

[How to add (clone) form fields using jQuery and increment ids and names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578111/how-to-add-clone-form-fields-using-jquery-and-increment-ids-and-names)

[jquery clone form fields and increment id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018132/jquery-clone-form-fields-and-increment-id)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this

```
$("#AmontTuy1Type").parent().clone().attr('id', 'newID').html()
```

It copy the select well, but the id of this one doesn't change?