# show/hide multiple hide buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

is it possible to make this show/hide script work with multiple hide buttons or something similar?  id="cv_cont should stay visible by default.

HTML

```
<button id="show_cv">Show</button>
<button id="hide_cv">Hide 1</button>
<button id="hide_cv">Hide 2</button>
<button id="hide_cv">Hide 3</button>
<button id="hide_cv">Hide 4</button>
<div id="cv_cont">Content Visible</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#hide_cv").click(function() {
    $("#cv_cont").hide();
});

$("#show_cv").click(function() {
    $("#cv_cont").show();
});
```

Original Location of the script.
[jQuery - failed show/hide buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658160/jquery-failed-show-hide-buttons)

Comment: Please ensure each button has a unique ID (are you intending to use a class?), these are the fundamental building blocks for HTML, CSS and JS to interact, please familiarize yourself with these things. Also we can't guess what your intentions are with the code. Can you describe in detail what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem here is all the hide buttons have the same ID's value, you can fix that by give them the same class's value and call it on the JavaScript code.

The correct code will like this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="show_cv">Show</button>
<button class="hide_cv">Hide 1</button>
<button class="hide_cv">Hide 2</button>
<button class="hide_cv">Hide 3</button>
<button class="hide_cv">Hide 4</button>
<div id="cv_cont">Content Visible</div>
  <script>
    $(".hide_cv").click(function() {
    $("#cv_cont").hide();
});

$(".show_cv").click(function() {
    $("#cv_cont").show();
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: LOL, You beat me to it, I was in the middle of writing my own fix that it's the same as what you got.   Thanks for the reinsurance.  :)

Comment: You are welcome anytime. ;)