# Show/Hide inside of Cloned div via dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, show

I've modified Josiah's answer from [clone form element with increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400592/clone-form-and-increment)
which is working well for me however now I need to extend it a little further with the abiltiy to show and hide additional fields from inside a cloned div

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/parkproductions/sxhbr25d/3/)

**I need to show div.hidden if #delivery_mode selection value is 1 or 2 and make sure it works for each cloned div.**

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var template = $('#products .product:first').clone();
var productsCount = 1;
window.addProduct = function(){
    productsCount++;
    var product = template.clone().find(':input, div').each(function(){
        var newId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.length-1) + productsCount;

        $(this).next().attr('for', newId); // update label for
        this.id = newId; // update id and name (assume the same)
        }).end()
        .attr('id', 'product' + productsCount)
        .appendTo('#products');
        }
$('.add').click(addProduct);

$("a#rp").click(function () {
if ($(".product").length != 1) {
    $(".product:last").remove();
    }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
 });
```

Array for days:

```
$days = array("0" => "Monday", "1" => "Tuesday", "2" => "Wednesday", 
 "3" => "Thursday", "4" => "Friday", "5" => "Saturday", "6" => "Sunday"); ?>
```

HTML

```
<div id="products">
        <div id="product1" class="product">

                    <div class="field" id="delivery_mode_1">
                        <label class="label has-text-white">Delivery Mode</label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <div class="select">


                                    <select name="delivery_mode[]" class="delivery_mode">
                                        <option value="0">Online</option>
                                        <option value="1">FT</option>
                                        <option value="2">PT</option>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="hidden">
                        @foreach($days as $day)
                            <input name="<?php echo $day; ?>[]" id="<?php echo $day; ?>_1" value="1" type="checkbox" class="is-checkradio is-white f_input" />
                            <label for="<?php echo $day; ?>_1"><?php echo $day; ?></label>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>


        </div>
</div>


<div class="field">
<div id="remove-product" class="control">
<a id="rp" class="button is-fullwidth is-link is-inverted is-outlined"><span 
class="icon is-small"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span><span>Remove 
Product</span></a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="field">
<div id="add-product" class="control">
<a id="ap" class="add button is-fullwidth is-link is-inverted is-outlined" >
<span class="icon is-small"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span><span>Add 
Product</span></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please create a working example

Comment: @brk fiddle added to question